# How to reset a list XNA and C#

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0, 2d-games

I need to do a "retry" option when the player finishes the game.For doing this I thought to reset the lists of Monsters and other objects that moved at the first playing or which have been "killed".for example I have a list like that:

```
   //the enemy1 class is already done
    // in Game1 I declare it
    List<enemy1> enem1 = new List<enemy1>();
    //Initialize method
    List<enemy1> enem1 = new List<enemy1>();
    //LoadContent
    foreach (enemy1 enemy in enem1)
    {
        enemy.Load(Content);
    }
    enem1.Add(new enemy1(Content.Load<Texture2D>("enemy"), new Vector2(5900, 12600)));

    //Update
    foreach (enemy1 enemy in enem1)
    {
        enemy.Update(gameTime);
    }
    //after being shooted the enemies disappear and i remove them
    //if the monsters are shooted the bool "visible" goes from false to true
    for (int i = enem1.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
         {
             if (enem1[i].visible == true)
                  enem1.RemoveAt(i);
          }
    //Draw
    foreach (enemy1 enemy in enem1)
        {
            if(enemy.visble==false)
          {
            enemy.Draw(spriteBatch, gameTime);
          }
        }
    //So my problem is to restart the game.
    if(lost==true)
    {
        //here I have to put the code that restore the list
          //I tried:
    foreach (enemy1 enemy in enem1)
        {
           enemy.visible=false;
        }
    }
   }

}
```

they should be drawn again but if I removed them they won't be drawn anymore.If I don't remove them ,instead, the enemies are in different places (because they follow me).
Any suggestions to restore or reinitialize the list??

Comment: Unrelated, but the past tense of `shoot` is `shot` (not shooted) :)

Comment: ahaha yeah.. you right. I am not english.. I from Italy and the english language that I know I've learned it on the interned and from the songs  :)

Comment: Recalling my good old days, we always used to build it you you would describe it: "A game has monsters", "A game has players". Which means you simply replace your game object with a new game object and everything gets built fresh. Reusing individual game elements for efficiency is a side-issue. :)

Comment: Why can't you just re-initialize your list how you create it in the beginning? By that I mean remove all enemies, then re-add all enemies with your foreach(...){enemy.Load(Content). I would think this should reset them to the same state they are when you start the game.

Comment: where can I add this code? in LoadContent it is already done

Comment: What about List.Clear();

Comment: nah.. it doesn't work

Comment: You should remove the == true / == false and instead use ! for false and nothing for true. If you are trying to start all the enemies at a certain position for a new game then use an initialize method and create them in there. Then when you need to start the new game clear the old list and call that function when needed to create a new enemy at that specific location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your question right but...
When restarting the game you could just empty the list

```
enem1.Clear();
```

and then refill it like you do at the first start of the game:

```
enem1.Add(new enemy1(....));
```